# Azure B2C Mobile and Email using both during sign up

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking for Singup/Singin policy which can allow user to use both email and mobile phone during sign up .   User can use either one of them during sign in.

Both email and mobile will be validated during the sign up.

Please suggest if there is any example i can refer to.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 0):

I have published a custom policy sample to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-samples).

[The **sign_up_sign_in** policy](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-samples/blob/master/Policies/src/sign_up_sign_in.xml) implements:

- **Sign-up** for a local account using an e-mail address *and* a phone number. The end user is prompted for verification of the e-mail address and the phone number.
- **Sign-in** for a local account using an e-mail address *or* a phone number. If the e-mail address hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the e-mail address. If the phone number hasn't been verified, then the end user is prompted for verification of the phone number.

Comment: Thanks @Chris appreciate your help